# Нет статики на главной странице сайта

Tags: python, django, docker, docker-compose, static

Занимаюсь проектом на Джанго, совместно с докером. В общем, статика есть в админке Джанго, но её нет на главной странице. Миграции делал, суперпользователя создал. Всё посмотрел, вроде всё корректно, прошу помощи у вас, может что-то упустил. Ниже прикрепляю docker-compose.yaml, default.conf и настройки проекта.

---

```
(docker-compose.yaml)

version: '3.8'

volumes:
  postgres_data:
  static_volume:
  media:

services:
  db:
    image: postgres:12.0-alpine
    volumes:
      - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data/
    env_file:
      - ./.env
    ports:
     - "5432:5432"
  web:
    image: bdcry/foodgram:latest
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - static_volume:/code/static/
      - media:/code/media
    depends_on:
      - db
    env_file:
      - ./.env
  nginx:
    image: nginx:1.19.0
    volumes:
      - media:/code/media
      - static_volume:/code/static/
      - ./default.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    depends_on:
      - web
```

---

```
default.conf

upstream foodgram {
    server web:8000;
}
server {
    listen 80;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://foodgram;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_redirect off;
    }
    location /static/ {
        alias /code/static/;
    }

    location /media/ {
        alias /code/media/;
    }
}
```

---

```
settings.py

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
```

---

```
(DockerFile)

FROM python:3.8.5

WORKDIR /code

COPY . .

RUN pip install -r /code/requirements.txt

CMD gunicorn foodgram.wsgi:application --bind 0.0.0.0:8000
```

Comment: я бы попробовал напрямую написать в браузере ссылку на какой нибудь статический элемнт страницы, и посмотрел на код ошибки - 404 будет? Может, папки для статики не туда, куда нужно, отмаплены? или в том месте, куд они отмаплены, нет содержимого?

Comment: в плане 'отмаплены'?

Comment: Ну, как я понимаю, у Вас есть докер контейнер, в котором запущена джанга. У неё есть "место хранения контента" - и, скорее всего, вы хотите, чтобы это место находилось "снаружи" контейнера, в файловой системе хоста. И вот туда то и могут быть (я прошу прощения, я не смотрел подробно на докер композ файл) отмаплены эти пути.

Comment: Еще нужно показать докер файл, который создает образ `bdcry/foodgram:latest`. Во время его сборки (или в его CMD/ENTRYPOINT, что хуже, но хотя бы так) есть команда `collectstatic`?

Comment: докерфайл прикрепил. сейчас зашёл в контейнер веба, посмотрел на статику - там файл админки и всё.

Comment: Ну вот, вы не вызываете нигде команду `collectstatic`. Она нужна, чтоб собрать статический файлы со всех сконфигурированных приложений в одно место (то куда указывает `STATIC_ROOT`).  Добавьте в Dockerfile команду `RUN python manage.py collectstatic`

Comment: помогло, спасибо)